# My app works fine in iOS12.4 but crashes in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

My app works fine in iOS 12.4 but crashed in iOS 11.

The following code is returning a nil in iOS 11.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)
{
    if characteristic == rxCharacteristic
    {
        if let ASCIIstring = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        {
            characteristicASCIIValue = ASCIIstring
            print("Value Recieved: \((characteristicASCIIValue as String))")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Notify"), object: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and be more specific. What exactly is `nil? Which line? Which value?

Comment: Don't force unwrap. Don't use `NSString` in Swift. You use an `if let...` but undo that by force unwrapping `characteristic.value`. Use something like `if let data=characteristic.value, let ASCII = String(data:data, encoding:.utf8) {`. Also be aware that different iOS devices have different BLE MTUs, as little as 20 bytes on older devices, so you may need to handle fragmentation and reassembly of the incoming string.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you use force unwrapping, you're looking for a crash when the value is not what you expect it to be, so avoid it:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)
{
    if characteristic == rxCharacteristic
    {
        if let value = characteristic.value, let ASCIIstring = NSString(data: value, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        {
            characteristicASCIIValue = ASCIIstring
            print("Value Recieved: \((characteristicASCIIValue as String))")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Notify"), object: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a million times, your answer was right and saved me hours of researching.

Comment: I am curious about why everything worked fine until IOS 11

Comment: Not sure exactly, but I would say that at some point you get more updates in the characteristic than before from CoreBluetooth. Some of those had no actual values and that's what crashed your app.